How to resolve the error 'Module parse failed: Unexpected token (13:12)' in react-native-web?
i'm trying building react-native with react-three-fiber on web by react-native-web
It works, but with react-three-fiber
Trying to import react-three-fiber/native according to the environment
I wrote the code as below.
import {Platform} from 'react-native';

type FiberType = typeof import('@react-three/fiber');
type FiberNativeType = typeof import('@react-three/fiber/native');
type DreiType = typeof import('@react-three/drei');
type DreiNativeType = typeof import('@react-three/drei/native');

let Fiber: FiberType | FiberNativeType;
let Drei: DreiType | DreiNativeType;

if (Platform.OS === 'web') {
  Fiber = require('@react-three/fiber') as FiberType;
  Drei = require('@react-three/drei') as DreiType;
} else {
  Fiber = require('@react-three/fiber/native') as FiberNativeType;
  Drei = require('@react-three/drei/native') as DreiNativeType;
}

export {Fiber, Drei};


When this code is executed, the following error occurs.
Failed to compile.
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (13:12)
node_modules/@react-native/assets-registry/path-support.js
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 'use strict';
| 
> import type {PackagerAsset} from './registry.js';
| 
| const androidScaleSuffix = {


for 10 days
After numerous searches, it seems that the webpack.config.js configuration is incorrect.
I tried many manuals but all failed,
As a result, my current ‘ webpack.config.js ' Current state.
I really don't know how to solve it, could you please point out what's wrong?
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin = require('@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin');

const appDirectory = path.resolve(__dirname, '../');

const babelConfig = require('../babel.config');

const babelLoaderConfiguration = {
  test: /\.(tsx|jsx|ts|js)?$/,
  exclude: /node_modules\/(?!react-native|nativewind|expo-gl)/,
  use: {
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
      cacheDirectory: true,
      presets: babelConfig.presets,
      plugins: ['react-native-web', ...(babelConfig.plugins || [])],
    },
  },
};

const imageLoaderConfiguration = {
  test: /\.(gif|jpe?g|png|svg)$/,
  use: {
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
      name: '[name].[ext]',
      esModule: false,
    },
  },
};

const fileLoaderConfiguration = {
  test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
        name: '[name].[ext]',
        outputPath: 'fonts/',
      },
    },
  ],
};

module.exports = argv => {
  return {
    entry: path.resolve(appDirectory, 'index'),
    output: {
      clean: true,
      path: path.resolve(appDirectory, 'web/dist'),
      filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
      sourceMapFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].map',
      chunkFilename: '[id].[chunkhash].js',
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: [
        '.web.ts',
        '.js',
        '.ts',
        '.web.tsx',
        '.tsx',
        '.android.tsx',
        '.ios.tsx',
      ],
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        babelLoaderConfiguration,
        imageLoaderConfiguration,
        fileLoaderConfiguration,
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      new ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin(),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: path.resolve(appDirectory, 'web/public/index.html'),
      }),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        __DEV__: argv.mode !== 'production' || true,
        process: {env: {}},
      }),
    ],
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
          commons: {
            test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
            name: 'vendor',
            chunks: 'initial',
          },
        },
      },
    },
  };
};


